# Keep navigation on the top after background image

Tags: html, css

I am really aware how to keep the navigation bar on the top by inserting `position:fixed;top:0;` in CSS. But, what I want is different from this one.

What I want is when I insert a new `div` (for image only) before navigation bar. So, when I open the web, I'd like to see the image first before I scroll the page down. After I scroll down the image, we can see a navigation bar there. And also when I keep scrolling down after navigation bar, I want the navigation bar sticks on top of the page.

The example of what I mean are [here](https://www.islandmediamanagement.com/).

So far what I have done is I have included `.home` before navigation bar. I have done is quite messy. Here are the coding below:

```css
.home {
min-height:400px; 
}

#header-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#headerleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
#header,
#top {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #E0E0E1;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#header p,
#top p {
  color: #FFF;
}
#header h1,
#top h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
#header h1 a,
#top h1 a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header h1 a:hover,
#top h1 a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
#headerleft h1 {
  font-family: Calibri sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#headerleft h1 a:hover {
  color: #CCC;
}
#nav {
  float: right;
}
#nav-icon img {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style:none;
}
#nav ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'alegreya_sansregular';
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px double #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <img src="assets/images/wallpaper.png" />
</div>

<div id="header">
  <div id="header-center">
    <div id="headerleft">
      <h1> <a href="#"> LOGO </a> </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
      <a href="" id="nav-icon">
        <img src="assets/images/navigation.png" alt="nav-menu">
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="link-nav" data-scroll-nav="0"> HOME </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="works"> WORKS </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-scroll-nav="1"> ABOUT </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-scroll-nav="2"> CONTACT </a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first set header to position:relative in css.  Then you would add jquery or javascript to say - when you scroll past 400px vertical (y) position, change position:relative to position:fixed.  That's usually how that works.

To answer your comment, you can add a css style:

```
.fixedPosition {
    position:fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then add jQuery (don't forget to put the library and the document ready function if needed):

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); 

    if (y > 400) {       
       $('#header').addClass('fixedPosition');
    } else { 
       $('#header').removeClass('fixedPosition'); 
    } 
});
```

HERE'S A **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/dd9uwxc1/16/)**

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and can you give me some javascript example where I can have a look at? Thanks.

Comment: It works - you may need to add more content so that it has enough to scroll down with - but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about you set the header to be `position: relative;` by default, and then in javascript detect if it hits the viewport top:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  if (document.getElementById('sticky-header').getBoundingClientRect().top < 1){
    $('#sticky-header').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0'});
  }
  // add code for reverse when you scroll up
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and can you give me some javascript example where I can have a look at? Thanks.